# Populate a table dynamically in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular. I have created an app that, given the click of a button, should trigger a call that gets a set of json objects and populate a specific table. In the following controller code I have managed to populate the table directly without the click of a button (via the this.tableParams), but what I want is to trigger this data fetching process and populate the table only when the populateTable() function is called.How do I do it?

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('anomalies')
    .controller('controller', ['$log', '$scope', '$http', 'NgTableParams', function ($log, $scope, $http, NgTableParams) {

        $scope.populateTable = function () {

            //

        }


        this.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, {
            filterDelay: 300,
            getData: function (params) {
                return $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: '/server/data.json'
                }).then(function (response) {
                    return response.data;
                }, function (response) {
                    $log.log(response);
                    return [];
                });
            }
        });

    }]);

})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not creating the `NgTableParams`-object inside the `populateTable`-function?

```
angular
    .module('anomalies')
    .controller('controller', ['$log', '$scope', '$http', 'NgTableParams', function ($log, $scope, $http, NgTableParams) {

    $scope.populateTable = function () {
      this.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, {
        filterDelay: 300,
        getData: function (params) {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/server/data.json'
            }).then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            }, function (response) {
                $log.log(response);
                return [];
            });
        }
      });
    }.bind(this);




}]);
```

Not the `.bind(this)`. This ensures the `this` keyword means the same inside the `populateTable`-function as in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Move `this.tableParams` into the `$scope.populateTable` function. Bind this function to a button in the view e.g `<button ng-click="populateTable()">Click Me!</button>`